# Can we download selected .xml files from server to our sdcard?

Tags: r

I am working.
On application downloading xml file.

Comment: `Are you check it ?` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472226/how-to-save-file-from-website-to-sdcard

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make any outbound HTTP connection you wish. If you know the URL of the file you want to download, just perform an HTTP GET on it.

you must request the INTERNET permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

From there, it's just a matter of using the Apache HTTP client libraries that are part of the Android SDK,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html

For an example using HTTP client, you can look at this source file,

> http://code.google.com/p/csdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/jtb/csc/CSCManager.java

and find the `readUrl()` method. there are many, many other examples of using Apache HTTP client out there, just Google for it.