# Can I only save and load bitmap format with internal storage

Tags: android

I want to save jpgs to disk. Do they need to be converted into bitmaps to be saved?

Comment: They are bitmaps in memory but JPG when saved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location

Comment: I see, so basically, images have to be converted into a bitmap to be saved to disk.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What needs to be converted to save to disk? What image are you trying to save?

Comment: I want to save jpgs to disk. Do they need to be converted into bitmaps to be saved?

Comment: Where and in what format do you have the images originally? Are they already jpg files? If they are in memory what format are they in?

Comment: They are on a server. They have a URL e.g. alsd3920jd0.jpg

Comment: Your question is not about images but about saving files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472226/how-to-save-file-from-website-to-sdcard

Comment: So I if I want to save a .jpg I need to save it like a file?

Comment: I understand now that I can save an image as a file, but even [a bit map it a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats)