# Publish apk created with Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, apk

I am developing an Android game with Libgdx. I want to publish my apk on the store, but the overall weight is 90 mb. How can I do? The file extension can be used in libgdx?

Comment: What`s "wrong" with apk of a game being 90mb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need have expansion files. Google Play doesn't let you upload more than 50 MB. So the rest needs to be attached. Take look on the link below.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: If I put all my images in the file extension I can take them with libgdx with the command Gdx.files.internal (path)?

Comment: No. How it works is, you upload your extra files when you upload the apk, but separately, then when the user downloads your application the user will also download your expansion files right after the downloading the apk.

Comment: Ok, but I can read this file on my libgdx project? In what way? This is my problem.

Comment: Yes, first you download it to a particular folder, then you can read those from there.

Comment: Otherwise it would be really useless, wouldn't it :)

Comment: Yes! :) But he extension file is downloaded with internet connection? And if the user turn off the connection after the download?

Comment: to download the expansion files you will need to use a library which handles pause/resume cases. So if the user turns off the connection and turn it on back again then the download will resume immediately.

Comment: So I would not have those files available and it is definitely necessary to put a control. But then there's a way not to see the images in the folder to the default gallery in android?

Comment: Yes, there is a way for it. Since Android is linux based you can prefix "." to your file name. (e.g : ".asd.jpg"). And check this SOF question as well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129644/how-to-make-a-file-hidden-in-android-sd-card)