# Hide a file from SD card

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sd-card, android-sdcard

Hi I have created a folder in sd card holding a db as below

```
public Databasehandler(Context context) 
{
    //super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "MyAppFolder"+ "/"+DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Now, I am trying to hide this file so that it is not accesible. I tried the below code.

```
 final String NOMEDIA_FILE = ".nomedia";

    path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "MyAppFolder" );
    path.mkdirs();

    file= new File(path,NOMEDIA_FILE);
    if (!file.exists()) 
    {
        try 
        {
            file.createNewFile();
            Log.e("NOMEDIA_FILE"," ");
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But, this is not working. Not sure how to hide the file in SDcard . Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129644/how-to-make-a-file-hidden-in-android-sd-card

Comment: Thanks for the link. where to include the .dbfile as said i the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Java 7 you can use the new java.nio.file.attribute package like so:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/j", "sa");
Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", true);
```

Or, if you're using an older version of Java and/or want to do it using Runtime, try this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C attrib -s -h -r your_path");
```

you can use it like this

```
final String NOMEDIA_FILE = ".nomedia";

    path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "MyAppFolder" );
    path.mkdirs();

    file= new File(path,NOMEDIA_FILE);
    Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", true);
```

**or**

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C attrib -s -h -r"+path);
    if (!file.exists()) 
    {
        try 
        {
            file.createNewFile();
            Log.e("NOMEDIA_FILE"," ");
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the second one and I get , java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [cmd.exe, /C, attrib, -s, -h, -r/mnt/sdcard/EaseTrailCount] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: i think u have not created the directory.So first create dir and then hide it

Comment: I have created the directory then using this code. Should I specify the db file path or the path of folder containing the db

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999437/how-to-make-a-folder-hidden-using-java

Comment: or try this.Put a file named .nomedia in the folder.